# XSLT: How to check if a child node has a specific name element and an empty value element?

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement

I need to check if the order element has a node "attribute" that has a child node "name" with the text SERIAL and a child node "value" that is empty.

Sample Input #1: No Serial number value.

```
 <orders>
       <order>
          <attributes>
             <attribute>
                <name>SERIAL</name>
                <value></value>
             </attribute>
             <attribute>
                <name>BATCH</name>
                <value>Batch1</value>
             </attribute>
          </attributes>
       </order>
    </orders>
```

Output for #1: No serial number

```
<externalorder>
   <batchnumbers>
     <batch>Batch1</batch>
   <batchnumbers>
</externalorder>
```

---

Sample Input #2: With serial number but without batch number

```
  <orders>
       <order>
          <attributes>
             <attribute>
                <name>SERIAL</name>
                <value>1</value>
             </attribute>
             <attribute>
                <name>SERIAL</name>
                <value>2</value>
             </attribute>
             <attribute>
                <name>BATCH</name>
                <value></value>
             </attribute>
          </attributes>
       </order>
    </orders>
```

Output for #2

```
<externalorder>
   <serialnumbers>
     <serialnumber>1</serialnumber>
     <serialnumber>2</serialnumber>
   <serialnumbers>
</externalorder>
```

Comment: Please expand your question to include context (who is "I" in "I have an attribute") and purpose (what do you want to do if/ otherwise). The version you are using -XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 - could also be important here.

Comment: Is it more clear now?

Comment: Just barely; the two options are not mutually exclusive nor exhaustive.   Anyway, does not the answer by Dan Field work for you?

Comment: It didn't work. By the way I'm using xslt version 1.

Comment: To explain further about my example, the input xml can have multiple "attributes" element that can either have a name element batch or serial. Now, if there's a value for batch it should output an element <batchnumbers> that has all the batch numbers and if it has a serial it will output an element <serialnumbers> with all the serial numbers in it. It's possible that it has an "attribute" element but without a value. That's the case where it should not output a batchnumbers or serialnumbers tag.

Comment: "*It didn't work*" is not a good description of a problem. Don't expect us to do **all** your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still the same basic problem: you want two templates, one to match `attribute[name='BATCH' and value!='']`, and one to match `attribute[name='SERIAL' and value!='']`.  I'll leave it to you to figure out how to suppress the empty node if you really need to do that.

Updated for new input/output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/orders/order">
    <externalorder>
        <serialnumbers>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="attributes/attribute[name='SERIAL' and value!='']" />
        </serialnumbers>
        <batchnumbers>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="attributes/attribute[name='BATCH' and value!='']" />
        </batchnumbers>

    </externalorder>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="attribute[name='SERIAL']">
    <serialnumber>
        <xsl:value-of select="value" />
    </serialnumber>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="attribute[name='BATCH']">
    <batch>
        <xsl:value-of select="value" />
    </batch>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You don't need the specify the same predicate twice.

Comment: How would I get it to call the correct template then?  If I take the predicate off one or the other both templates end up being called, unless I'm just misunderstanding you

Comment: Ok this one worked. I just have to add an xsl:if for it not to display the batchnumbers/serialnumbers if there's no value. Thanks Dan!

Comment: I meant the `and value!=''` part; you can remove that from the match pattern. The template matching text() is also redundant, IMHO.

Comment: Ahh got it.  Yeah, I had the text() match in there and forgot to take it out - at one point I wasn't matching all the nodes and wanted to suppress the extra text.  Edited.